# python 3 re.findall Выводит пустые значения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Есть скрипт, который по регулярке ищет в логе значения, но я получаю не только искомое значение, но ещё и пустые строки.
Вот пример вывода, как получить только значения где есть текст?

```
[('0', 'R', 'ER')]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[('80', 'S', 'ER')]
[]
[('21:55:21.210', 'SEVERE', 'ER')]
[]
[]
```

`def FindError():`

```
patterrn1 = r'([\d\:.]+).{6}([SEVERE]+).*(ER\d{3})'
regexeper = re.compile(patterrn1)
print(regexeper)
with open(ExistLogs) as in_file:
    with open(ResultFile, 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            try:
               test1 = regexeper.findall(line)
               print(test1)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
```

Пока нашел решение собственно условие проверки, не знаю на сколько это корректно, но работает

```
test1 = regexeper.findall(line)
                   #print(test1)
                   if test1 == []:
                       pass
                   else:
                       print(test1)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
```

Comment: Используйте `if lst:` вместо `if lst == []:` для проверки есть ли элементы в списке.

Comment: Регулярные выражения ни при чем. Кратко вопрос без воды звучит так: `как проверить пуст ли массив в python?`

Comment: @ReinRaus да скорее всего, так более грамотнее звучит вопрос, но почему добавляются пустые строки, мне этого не понятно,  может это как-то связанно с построчным чтением файла?

Comment: `[SEVERE]` так же из этой части можно убрать повторяющиеся E: `[SEVR]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой ответ: да, у вас выполняется построчное чтение из файла лога, каждая строка анализируется регулярным выражением и результат выводится на печать. Если регулярное выражение не сработало, оно возвращает пустой список (вовсе необязательно оборачивать поиск в блок try: except, re.findall не возбуждает исключение на пустых строках)

вот эффективный способ выполнить задачу при помощи выражений-генераторов:

```
import re
regexeper = re.compile(r'([\d\:.]+).{6}([SEVERE]+).*(ER\d{3})')    
parsed_lines = (regexeper.findall(line) for line in open(ExistLogs) if regexeper.findall(line))
for parsed_line in parsed_lines:
    print parsed_line
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобраться бы ещё в генераторах, я только учусь)

Comment: Вот материалы по итераторам и генераторам:
https://xakep.ru/2014/10/06/generatora-iteratory-python/
https://youtu.be/FlOQ6uAGQfA?t=53m41s

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться